# What is the best option to note the serial number on a presentation?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I'm writing many presentations (by Power-Point) while each one of them is just a part (another part) of one subject, and I want to put serial numbers on each one of the presentations (on the first page, where my name is mentioned)

Can I write

> "Part no. 1"

To me it sounds a little weird, I do not know how to explain it, but I think that I never saw such thing.

If you have another / better option, please let me know and I'll be very grateful.

Comment: I think what you want is not a *serial number* exactly - a serial number is usually used to show the order in which identical parts were manufactured.  But you might say something like "Part one of five" if the presentations form a series.  [Here is an example of this kind of usage.](https://books.google.com/books?id=L_E8CgAAQBAJ)

Comment: @ stangdon, thank you for your comment. Actually I need something without "of" since I don't know actually the number of the series.  In the other hand, I'm not used to see "part 1" but maybe I'm wrong. What is the acceptable way to note that thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I see, it's acceptable to use

> "**Part 1:** Here is the subject".

I attached picture below (I found it on Google)

[image]

Comment: I would capitalize the word "Part," as was done in your image.

Comment: That should be "Here **is** the subject".

Comment: You're right. it's edited thanks to your comment. Thank you.